# Could reserved block count of zero hinder `fsck`?

Tags: linux, ext4, fsck, tune2fs

I am considering setting the reserved block percentage to 0% (`tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sdb1`) for an `ext4` partition. The partition is only used by non-privileged users anyway.

Let's say I mistakenly fill up the partition to 100% and the filesystem becomes corrupt. **Does `fsck` require some free disk space to be able to run?** I obviously would like to be able to repair the file system if it breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/a/131551) answer states:

> Reserved space is there for a reason: it lowers the fragmentation chances and saves some space for `fsck`. It is reserved only from users, but root (and thus all your software installs) can fully use it. If you think 5% is excessive, leave at least 1% .

So, I guess the answer is; **Yes, `fsck` needs some space available to run.**